# How to set excerpt of a post in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

Instead of using auto-generated excerpt, I'm trying to set a custom excerpt in post's YAML frontmatter.

```
---
layout: post
title: My Post
excerpt: My custom excerpt
---
```

But this custom excerpt doesn't get picked up in my post list page. My index.html template looks like this

```
<div class="home">
  <div class="posts">
    {% for post in paginator.posts %}
      <div class="post py3">
        <p class="post-meta">{{ post.date | date: site.date_format }}</p>
        <a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}" class="post-link"><h3 class="h1 post-title">{{ post.title }}</h3></a>
        <p class="post-summary"> {{ post.excerpt }} </p>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

  {% include pagination.html %}
</div>
```

I'm using `jekyll@3.7.2` and have `jekyll-pagination` plugin enabled. It should be pretty straight-forward, but I just cannot figure out what's going wrong. Am I missing anything?

**Update**

Actually I've made a very dumb mistake that I'm editing the wrong files. And setting excerpt actually does work.

Answer (score 1):

`post.excerpt` is assigned by Jekyll, so, you cannot reassign it.

You can change the name of your variable to `myexcerpt`.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to use a different variable 'summary', and update to the template to `{{ post.summary }}`. The output is empty string.

Comment: repository url for debug ??

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem, and I figure out it was because of the length of the custom excerpt. If I reduce it to some amount of words, it worked. Otherwise, I will get a empty string.